# Passing attribute from blade to route to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax to use here in both the href link in my blade and the {id} passing in the route, but the documentation for laravel (5.8) has me a bit confused.

My controller function should be good, but I'm wondering how I would appropriately pass an ID (currently echoed in the blade) properly through the button href link, and then handle that ID properly in the route so that I get not only the page at the url `id\progress` but also get the $id in the controller function.

Am I on the right track?

blade.php

```
<?php echo($id) ?>
<button><a href=""></a></button>
```

web.php (routes)

```
Route::get('/{id}/progress', 'Track\TrackProgressController@index')
->name('track.progress');
```

TrackProgressController

```
public function index($id)
{

}
```

Comment: Yes you are on the right track just add url in your achor tag like:

<a href="{{ route('track.progress', $id) }}"></a>

Comment: Did you check the Laravel documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel variable in herf tag like:

```
{{ route('track.progress', ['id' => $id]) }}
```

However, you are passing `$id` correctly in your routes and function

**Route**

```
 Route::get('/{id}/progress', 'Track\TrackProgressController@index')
->name('track.progress');
```

**Funcation**

```
public function index($id)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I do this and have my controller function say return view with $id then it will work as is, I don't have to do anything else to get it inside that function?

Comment: Yes, Don't need to do anything to get the `$id` inside your function

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code like this in blade:

```
<button><a href="/{{$id}}/progress"></a></button>
```

which will pass the $id as a param to the route. Your route will be like this

```
Route::get('/{id}/progress', 'Track\TrackProgressController@index')->name('track.progress');
```

You can access the id in controller like this:

```
public function index($id = null)
{
    dd($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the correct path, but please change your route definition to match the correct syntax from official documentation:

```
Route::get('/progress/{id}', 'Track\TrackProgressController@index')
->name('track.progress');
```

Then, you can add id as your route parameter in your view:

```
<button><a href="/progress/{{$id}}"></a></button>
```

Or another way, since you have a route name:

```
<button><a href="{{ route('track.progress',['id' => $id])}}"></a></button>
```

Then, all you have to do is to retrieve that id inside your controller, like this:

```
public function index($id)
{
  echo 'Retrieved id = '.$id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass single (parameter) `id` from `blade` to `controller` you can simple use `href` if you are using get method..

Blade:

```
<a href="{{ route('track.progress', $id)}}"></a>
```

Web.php:

```
Route::get('/{id}/progress', 'Track\TrackProgressController@index')
->name('track.progress');
```

Controller:

```
public function index($id)
{
        // do something
}
```

and to pass multiple parameters to controller then you can use `array[]` in route method:

```
<a href="{{ route('multi.params', ['param1'  => 'param1', 'param2' => 'param2'])}}"></a>
```

Route for Multiple Params:

```
Route::get('/{param1}/{param2}', 'MyController@MyMethod')->name('multi.params');
```

Controller:

```
public function MyMethod($param1, $param2)
{
        // do something
}
```

Thanks